# Is it possible to package .exe file in jar and run it in processbuilder?

Tags: java, maven

I am writing a java program which calls an external binary file `process.exe`. When I packing my program in to jar, I want to include this external binary file. And when I executing the packaged jar file `java -jar my-program.jar`, I want the included `.exe` file to be directly runnable inside the jar. (assuming the executing environment is Windows)

Is this doable using Maven? Any example are appreciated.